# Where is my free space?

Tags: windows-vista, disk-space

A week ago I got a low disk space warning on my Vista x64 Ultimate box - 60 Mb free on the disk C; I cleaned up some downloaded msdn images and got 20 Gb freed up. Three days ago I got another notification, it looked suspicious but I didnt have time to deal with it and just moved some heavy stuff to another drive to free up about 17 Gb....

Today morning - 53Mb left on drive C, again! Now it looks really suspecious, so I downloaded TreeSize to see what's taking up the space, just to see it reporting only 121 GB out of 200 GB used, in other words I suppose to have about 79 Gb free. Then I went to Folder Options, enabled viewing of system and hidden files, rerun teh tool to see another 5 Gb added (which is expected). Then I open disk C in windows explorer, select all and right click Properties, to see it reporting teh same amount of files - 126 Gb. But when I look at Drive C properties, it reports that 200GB of 200 Gb are taken.

I just scanned the drive with two different antiviruses - Symantec and AVG and found no viruses...

I'm a little confused at this point, any ideas where is my free space, woudl be highly appreciated!

Thank you!
Andrey

Comment: Perform an error check on the drive, it could be something as simple as a disk directory error

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like some kind of virus/malware. I see that you ran a few AV scans but you should also run a few malware scans. Try [AdAware](http://download.cnet.com/Ad-Aware-Free-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10045910.html?part=dl-ad-aware&subj=dl&tag=top5) and [Malwarebytes](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html?part=dl-10804572&subj=dl&tag=button).

Comment: AdAware *used* to be on my recommend list: but it's a total resource hog now :(  .. I still like Spybot-SD and MS' malware scanner is decent, too.

Answer (score 2):

One program designed to help you answer the question "where did my diskspace go?" is [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). It summarizes the distribution of data across the filesystem like this:

[image]

If this suggests that the cause is indeed sinister, you may also want to try some of the tools from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx), especially [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), though I would suggest that you download the [entire suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) to save time later if/when you want to try another of the tools. Process Explorer allows you to see what DLLs are loaded in each process, what system handles processes hold, and what sockets they have open, and it makes a pretty good replacement for Task Manager: the only thing I'm aware of that Task Manager can do but Process Explorer can't do is list win16 processes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your temporary files through the Disk Cleanup wizard? It could be there has just been a lot of Internet traffic or other miscellaneous work that is sitting clogged on your machine.

Comment: I have run CCleaner to remove all temp files; also, the problem is that space has disappeared mystically - TreeSize reports that I only use 121 Gb out of 200, so 79 GB just disappeared!